# ref current is null when call componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

It's for the first time when I try to use ref in React.

I have this code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        percent: 100,
    };
    this.node = createRef();
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.resetHandlebarPosition();
    console.log(this.node);
    this.node.current.fitToViewer();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div
            className={styles.stageView}
            onClick={this.onStageClick}
            role="presentation"
        >
            <AutoSizer>
                {(({ width, height }) => width === 0 || height === 0 ? null : ( // eslint-disable-line
                    <ReactSVGPanZoom
                        width={width}
                        height={height}
                        ref={this.node}
                        detectAutoPan={false}
                        toolbarPosition={'left'}
                        miniaturePosition={'left'}
                        toolbarProps={{ SVGAlignX: 'center', SVGAlignY: 'center' }}
                        background={'#f1f3f2'}
                        className={styles.viewer}
                    >
                        <svg
                            width={svgwidth}
                            height={svgheight}
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            xlinkHref="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                            style={"padding-top: 15px"} // eslint-disable-line
                        >
                            <g
                                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ // eslint-disable-line
                                    __html: this.props.svgString,
                                }}
                            />
                        </svg>
                    </ReactSVGPanZoom>
                ))}
            </AutoSizer>
            <StageHandler />
        </div>
    );
}
```

My problem is, that in componentDidMount in this.node current is null and I don't know why. It seems that the component doesn't render in DOM when componentDidMount was called.

Comment: Which Version of React are you using ?

Comment: Maybe it's because when your component first render, the width or height were equal to 0, and so you're returning null and `ReactSVGPanZoom` is not rendering

Comment: Your right Mohamed, but how can I resolve this ? My component renders 5 or 6 times, until all components are rendered to DOM.